# What does |% mean in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I've come across this today:

```
$tests = (Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -Name bin |% { Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse -Filter *.Unit.Tests.dll } |% {  $($_.FullName) })
Write-Host ------------- TESTS -----------
Write-Host $tests
Write-Host -------------------------------
.\tools\xunit\xunit.console.exe $tests -xml test-report.unit.xml
```

I can't get my head around what '|%' is doing there. Can anyone explain what it used for please?

Comment: It's an alias for Foreach-Object: `get-alias -definition foreach-object`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`%` is an [alias](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847830.aspx) for [the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849731.aspx).

An alias is just another name by which you can reference a cmdlet or function. For example `dir`, `ls`, and `gci` are all aliases for `Get-ChildItem`.

`ForEach-Object` executes a `[ScriptBlock]` *for each* item passed to it through the pipeline, so piping the results of one cmdlet into `ForEach-Object` lets you run some code against each individual item.

In your example, `Get-ChildItem` is finding all of the `bin`s in a certain directory tree, and then *for each one that is found*, `Get-ChildItem` is being used to find all of the files underneath that match `*.Unit.Tests.dll`, and then *for each one of those*, the full name is returned to the pipeline (which is getting assigned to the `$tests` variable).

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @briantist's answer:

The `|` is the pipeline operator. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-6):

> Each pipeline operator sends the results of the preceding command to the next command.

To demonstrate:

```
Get-ChildItem bin | % { Get-ChildItem $_  }
```

could be rewritten as:

```
Get-ChildItem bin | Foreach-Object { Get-ChildItem $_ }
```

or *without* using the pipeline but a [foreach loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-6) instead (which is **different** from the [foreach command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-6)!):

```
foreach ($item in (Get-ChildItem bin)) { Get-ChildItem $item }
```